# SOAP::RPC::Driver formatting problems. How can I change it?

Tags: ruby, soap, soap-client

I'm dealing with a SOAP webservice call from a server that is expecting to receive method calls with the paramaters in the format of:

```
<urn:offeringId> 354 </urn:offeringId>
```

But SOAP::RPC::Driver is generating messages in the form of:

```
<offeringId xsi:type = "xsd:int">354</offeringId>
```

The server keeps erroring when it gets these messages (especially since it's expecting offeringId to be a custom type internal to itself, not an int).

Is there anyway to configure the driver to format things the way the server is expecting it. Is the server even doing SOAP? I'm having trouble finding reference to that style of formating for SOAP (I know it DOES work though, because SOAPUI works just fine with that type of message).

-Jenny

Edit: I've got at least part of it solved. the RPC::Driver (obviously) uses the RPC standard, whereas apparently the server I'm trying to talk to is doing "document". Now, when I look at RPC::Driver's API, I'm seeing a method named "add_document_method". That SOUNDS to me like it might be what I want, but I can't figure out what paramaters to give it. The examples I've seen around the net don't make much sense to me, things like:

```
def GetNamePair(response)
  response.account.each do |x| 
    class << x
      attr :configuration, true    
    end     
    x.configuration = Hash[*x.a.map do |y|
      [y.__xmlattr[XSD::QName.new(nil, 'n')], String.new(y)]
    end.flatten] 
  end
end

mNS = 'urn:zimbraAdmin'
drv.add_document_method('GetAllAdminAccountsRequest', mNS, [XSD::QName.new(mNS, 'GetAllAdminAccountsRequest')],  
  [XSD::QName.new(mNS, 'GetAllAdminAccountsResponse')] )  

puts YAML.dump(GetNamePair(drv.GetAllAdminAccountsRequest([]))
```

All I really know is that I have a method that takes in certain parameters.... I really don't get why, if this method does what I think it does, it has to be more complicated. Isn't this just a matter of taking the exact same data and formating it differently? I'm so confused....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what I ended up doing was using SOAP:RPC:Drivers add_document_method, which requires me to give it the wsdl, namespace, etc, and then give it the attributes later as a single input hash thingy (and gives me the output in a similar format). It worked, it just wasn't as clean as add_rpc_method (which is waht add_method defaults to)

-Jenny